# Loading zend component from service/model

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

If I want to call a zend compoment class from an Entity or Service I get the following error:

Warning: require(../library/\LG\Services\Zend_Db_Table.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Demos\Example\library\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php on line 148

I'm trying to use this:
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

I think there's some kind of autoloader conflict? 
The service is using the following namespace
namespace LG\Services;

How can I make this work correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your autoloader is either configured incorrectly, or your code uses namespaces and you forgot to prefix the ZF class name with a \ - but without further information it's a bit hard to give anything more specific.

Comment: Actually my services do use namespaces (LG\services) what do you mean with prefix ZF class with \? do I need to configure a special autoloader for calls like this? BTW: I register a Doctrine ClassLoader for the Services/Entities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either place this at the top of your script under the namespace declaration

```
use \Zend_Db_Table;
```

or prefix the class with a backslash, eg

```
$db = \Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

Both methods inform PHP that the `Zend_Db_Table` class exists in the global namespace. Without it, PHP will assume that the class exists in the current namespace (`\LG\Services`).

Comment: Thanks that works. BTW where in the documentation is this? I mean that I have to put "use \Zend_FOO" or backlask. I've reading/working with the framework just for a week, but havent found that

Comment: @dimirc This isn't ZF specific but core PHP. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php